# Changing file path to a more common folder

Tags: java, android, export-to-csv

I currently have a simple code in which i save a CSV file in a folder, according to my android studio monitor i am successfully saving that file in a folder i can't access which is "/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfolder/552.csv".

```
File path =new 
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment. + 
DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"myfolder");

    System.out.println(path);
    if (!path.exists()){
        path.mkdir();
    }
    File mypath=new File(path,(editSesion.getText().toString()+".csv"));
    FileWriter mFile = new FileWriter(mypath,true);
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(mypath));
    System.out.println(mypath);
```

Is there any way to obtain the path to a more commonly accesable folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**/storage/emulated/0/Download/** is the Downloads folder of your phone storage.

How much common directory are you expecting than this?

Comment: How can i access that folder though my phone, or my computer?

Comment: Open internal storage from file manager, then go to the downloads folder.

Comment: ... Thats the issue im having i cant acces that /0/ folder through ES File Explorer or any other file manager app i have installed.

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/ is the internal storage directory. You can directly view the contents of internal storage from any file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Please add **/** (Forward slash) like this **myfolder/**

```
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment. + 
DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"myfolder");
```

change into

```
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment. + 
DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"myfolder/");
```